# Warpped object delected Using pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 193, in __draw_idle_agg
    if self.height() < 0 or self.width() < 0:
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of %S has been deleted
```

Why is it using QT5 file though?

I have imported only QT4. It has been working fine prior to this AND the code does continue to run, but prints this in the ide.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
```

Having read similar online questions, I get the gist that you cannot fix this?

Comment: show complete code please.

Comment: Add these 2 lines at the top of the file: `import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')`